# Magento 2 - Get attribute label by id in controller

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, labels

I am passing attribute id in my controller's URL and I am taking that id as below in my controller,

`$colorparam =$this->getRequest()->getParams('color');`

This returns me the id present in the controller. Now, I want the label or say it's an option from this id without using any product instance.

For example: I have attribute id -50 but I want it's label as Red.

I want to get this without loading any specific product in my controller.

Comment: You want to get attribute label or attribute option label here ?

Comment: I want attribute option by it's value in my custom controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your controller file

```
protected $optionFactory;

protected $_attributeOptionCollection;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterfaceFactory $optionFactory,
  \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection $attributeOptionCollection
){
    $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
    $this->_attributeOptionCollection = $attributeOptionCollection;
}

public function execute()
{
    $optionValue = 50;
    $optionFactory = $this->optionFactory->create();
    $optionFactory->load($optionValue);
    $attributeId = $optionFactory->getAttributeId();
    $optionData = $this->_attributeOptionCollection
                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                    ->setIdFilter($optionValue)
                    ->setStoreFilter()
                    ->load();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($optionData->getFirstItem()->getValue()); exit;
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hi, The last line $optionData->getData() is giving me all data. I just want value.

Comment: Can you please use this ? **$optionData->getFirstItem()->getValue()**

Comment: I've updated code in answer as well.

Comment: Thanks Buddy. Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Run this below script from your root folder :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend'); // adminhtml

$eavConfig = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection');

$attributeId = 93;
$attribute = $eavConfig
    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
    ->setStoreFilter()
    ->load();
foreach ($attribute as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['value'] . "<br/>";
}
exit;
```